# There is option to get expected type of variable in PHP?

Tags: php, php-7.2

I have method which cast array to object by using

```
$class = get_class($object);
$methodList = get_class_methods($class);
```

But now I need had information about expected type of variable too. For example from this method:

```
public function setFoo(int $foo)
{
}
```

I need get `int` too. There is any option to get it?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionparameter.gettype.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Reflection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php). Specifically [`ReflectionParameter::getType()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionparameter.gettype.php).

```
function someFunction(int $param, $param2) {}

$reflectionFunc = new ReflectionFunction('someFunction');
$reflectionParams = $reflectionFunc->getParameters();
$reflectionType1 = $reflectionParams[0]->getType();
$reflectionType2 = $reflectionParams[1]->getType();

assert($reflectionType1 instanceof ReflectionNamedType);
echo $reflectionType1->getName(), PHP_EOL;
var_dump($reflectionType2);
```

The above example will output:

```
int
NULL
```